# getting basename with globbing when trailing / is present

Tags: bash, glob, tab-completion

```
input1="/$HOME/Desktop/foo/bar/"
input2="/$HOME/Desktop/foo/bar"
target1a=$(basename "$input1")
target1b="${input1##*/}"
target2a=$(basename "$input2")
target2b="${input2##*/}"

echo $target1a
echo $target1b
echo $target2a
echo $target2b
```

returns

```
bar

bar
bar
```

is there a way to get `target1b` to also return `bar`?

Do to tab completion in bash, `$1` can often be entered into the cli as in `input1` or `input2` variations and I would like to be able to use globbing instead of `basename` to return `bar` when either variation is entered.

Comment: `${input##*/}` doesn't use a regex at all.  (It's a glob)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you want to avoid `basename` for the overhead of creating the child process needed to run an external utility.

If so, the following, which uses Bash's regex-matching operator, `=~`, may do:

```
[[ $input1 =~ ([^/]+)/?$ ]] && target1b=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

Regex `([^/]+)/?$` capture the last (`$`) path component (`[^/]+`), excluding a trailing `/`, if present (`/?`).

The results of the regex-matching operation are stored in special array variable `${BASH_REMATCH[@]}`, which Bash populates after every use of `=~`.
What the path-component-matching subexpressions matched is available as element `1`, due to being the 1st (and here only) subexpression enclosed in `(...)`, commonly called a *capture group* (element `0` always contains the overall match).

Answer (score 2):

I see you already accepted [mklement0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42233464/2877364) (makes sense!), but here's one pure glob, in case it helps anyone else —

```
target1b="${input1%/}"       # Strip the trailing slash, if any
target1b="${target1b##*/}"   # Now drop the leading directory components
```